# iOS Provisioning Profile name

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

As I'm creating an iOS provisioning profile I'm presented with this screen:

[image]

To my -limited- understanding, the profile already has everything I will need to identify it such as the `Type` and `App ID`. **Why do I need to name it? Is this name relevant in the future?** (so if I screw up and give it a meaningless name will I be able to change it in the future?)

I can't find this info in the Apple sea of docs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The name you provide is simply used to identify the profile within the Member Center.  It's generally more human-readable (friendly) than the App ID.

It *is* possible to edit the name later, if you want to change it in the future!

The name of the profile also appears on a provisioned device.  You can find profiles within **Settings**, under General->Profiles.  (If a device has no profile, the Profiles setting won't be present.)

Comment: Also, if you have different sets of devices that you want to maintain different provisioning profiles for, you can make the name appropriate for that device set.  Again, it's still just a more human friendly name, but another possible use for the name field.